# Json Parsing error in RoR forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I am building simple rails app to handle pay per printed paged accounting for leased copiers.
I have client_devices and counter_reports resources.
For each client device agents neeeds to manually enter current mono counter and color counter at the end of each month using /counter_reports/new with id of the deviece passed in params.
I want to use ajax to calucalte current payment for each device so agent can see the payment on the web just after entering mono counter (in the field with #cpa id in view.).

However I keep getting error like this below.

Any thought how to overcome this? I've read tons of posts and nothing helps.

```
Started POST "/counter_reports" for ::1 at 2015-04-08 19:59:46 +0200
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

mono_counter=22

ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (795: unexpected token at 'mono_counter
=22'):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:53:in `resc
ue in parse_formatted_parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:32:in `pars
e_formatted_parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:23:in `call
```

This shows that somehows 22 or any other enetered number is passed to the varaible but can't be processed...

My entry form is

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :report_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :report_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :mono_counter %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :mono_counter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :color_counter %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :color_counter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="number" name="counter_report[current_payment]" id="cpa">
  </div>
```

My **counter_reports.js is**

```
$(document).on("change","#counter_report_mono_counter",function(){
  var mono_counter = $(this).val();
  //var age = $("#id_of_age_input").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/counter_reports",
    data: { "mono_counter" : mono_counter },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"
  });
});
```

My **calculate_rate.js.erb**

```
$("#cpa").val(@current_payment);
```

**My counter_reports_controller.rb**

```
def calculate_rate
  @actual = params[:mono_counter]

  @result = @actual * 2
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}  
  end
end
```

**routes.rb is:**

```
 post "/counter_reports" => "counter_reports#calculate_rate" , as: "calculate_rate"
```

Comment: Have you tried passing a reference to the object in the data attribute of the ajax call? Or changing the name of the key in the object and changing the params reference to match?

Comment: Can you post the JSON object that you are posting to the server ?

Comment: do you have Postman Restclient installed on your browser If not then please install it and check your url there.It is an very useful tool for testing the api url and ajax urls.

Comment: @JamesDullaghan can you please explain or give some example?

Comment: @bsvin33t I am new to rails thus not really sure what do you mean by JSON object? I have posted all the code which references to this functions.

Comment: @Maciek var params = { 'mono_counter': mono_counter }
and then data: params. I doubt this would make any difference, but it's worth a shot.